# Trying to have CSS styling that can be applied via an onclick button event

Tags: css, button, hyperlink, onclick, stylesheet

I am currently learning web design and web development, and have created a website as a means of demonstrating what I have learned at [http//.www.ahandbuilt.website](http://www.ahandbuilt.website)

(yes, I know it looks a mess, but I'm still learning and it appears I'm trying to run before I can walk)

On the home page you will see three buttons that are intended to provide onclick changes to the page.

The first two buttons are designed so the home page can be viewed with CSS styling applied or with out CSS styling applied - as a means of showing the effects of CSS on the appearance of a page.

In the head of my HTML document, I have a css link tag as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
```

and have a stylesheet titled handbuilt.css

So, the page opens without any styling, but when the appropriate button is clicked it should update the css link's href value:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="handbuilt.css">
```

and vice versa.

The problem is the button isn't changing the href in the link. I would be grateful of any pointers. I'm not after a full answer - just a pointer as to where I'm going wrong.

Site rules I am working with, mean I can only work with straight code, no frameworks. My abilities at the moment mean I'm working comfortably with HTML, ok with CSS and struggling with JavaScript.

Any advice or pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you got it working! Hope my answer helped.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions. I spent a few days learning to understand where I was going wrong before testing and uploading, and also playing with other button onclick operations.

Answer (score 1):

> Any advice or pointers will be much appreciated.

Try opening [developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) in your browser (I use firebug in Firefox but built-in dev tools are great too) and look at the console output when you click on the button. If you're not already familiar with dev tools, definitely check them out. They'll make your coding life much easier.

> I'm not after a full answer - just a pointer as to where I'm going
>   wrong.

When I look at my Firebug console while clicking the button,  I'm seeing an error `ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`.

It seems like you're calling the myFunction function before it's defined. The browser doesn't know what to do with it so the function isn't being executed.

There might be other problems, but I would start by trying to get this function to actually execute.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions. I spent a few days learning to understand where I was going wrong before testing and uploading, and also playing with other button onclick operations.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

In head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style1.css" id="styling">
```

In body:

```
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="toggleCSS()"> Toggle CSS </button>
```

JS:

```
  function toggleCSS()
  {
    var link = document.getElementById('styling');
    link.disabled = !link.disabled;
  }
```

By this code, I'm enabling and disabling the CSS by a button event. Simple !!!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery need :

```
$("link:first").attr('href',"handbuilt.css");
```

for example

```
<button onclick="$('link:first').attr('href','handbuilt.css');">Click to see page with Styling</button>
```

for JS need giving id for link element. For example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" id="styleid">
```

and then

```
document.getElementById("styleid").href = "handbuilt.css"
```

for example (this is work in your site)

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('styleid').href = 'handbuilt.css'">Click to see page with Styling</button>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions. I spent a few days learning to understand where I was going wrong before testing and uploading, and also playing with other button onclick operations.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do so you need to use javascript to dynamically update the HTML code of your page. You already have a javascript function linked to your button (myFunction0, you now need to include proper javascript code to update the stylesheet.

you should have something like this in your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
    //your code
}
</script>
```

You can find an idea of what to write in this function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510347/dynamically-load-stylesheets).
That should be enough for you to solve this!

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions. I spent a few days learning to understand where I was going wrong before testing and uploading, and also playing with other button onclick operations.

Comment: Gald to hear that, keep up the good work, you are on the right track :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at your JavaScript function, you are using the method 'getElementById'. As I'm sure you know, you can add an Id attribute to your elements in HTML. That's exactly what this method is looking for. To verify, you can open your developer tools (in Chrome you can use F12 or right click and select 'Inspect'). In developer tools, there is a console where you can write JavaScript, and it will return you results. It's also where information logged with console.log() etc. will be displayed. Try adding an Id to and element and using the 'getElementById' method in the console to see what it returns.

Once you've explored this, you may want to know that you can modify an element's attributes with JavaScript once you've selected it. Some self-exploration or Googling will tell you how to do this. This way you can just modify what exactly your link is bringing to the page..

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions. I spent a few days learning to understand where I was going wrong before testing and uploading, and also playing with other button onclick operations.

Comment: @AndrewBrown: Just checkout out your website again, and I'm glad you got your issue worked out. I know it may not be exactly what you're looking for at the moment, but if you haven't already, you should definitely check out jQuery. It's very powerful.