# change Style sheet when different language is selected.

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a angular 6 application which supports standard Left to write content. 
I need arabic support so I did some research and got to know about Bootsrap RTL. 
I need to know if it is possible to reload the whole style.scss file on selecting a language in home page . If I select Arabic then RTL should be loaded or else LTR be default. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Remove old stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033650/how-to-dynamically-remove-a-stylesheet-from-the-current-page) [Add new stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510347/dynamically-load-stylesheets)

Comment: Just change the `href` of your `<link rel="stylesheet">`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the `lang` attribute of the `root` element (`<html>`) via JS and set in css the `rtl` direction based on that attribute, so there's no need to load another resource, e.g.

**JS** (switch language)

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute('lang', 'ar');
```

**CSS**

```
body { 
   direction: ltr;
}

[lang="ar"] body {
   direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Works perfect and easy approach. Thanks brother.

Comment: one more question. Do you know how can i manipulate @Import in style.scss after using SetAttribute? Basically I want to import bootstrap.rtl file on change of attribute.

Comment: man i got stuck on this for weeks. really elegant and awesome solution. thank you

Answer (score -1):

Natively browser supports dir attribute to div elements, so you could do the direction to be modified via an dir attribute.

```
<div dir="ltr">Hello World. This gets displayed from left to right</div>
<div dir="rtl">Hello World. This gets displayed from right to left</div>
```

Pass the dynamic variable from ts file for angular application,

```
<div dir="[direction]"></div>
```

set the direction value to ltr/rtl based on the configuration from angular application